# Getting Roster from XMPP in Swift

Tags: swift, xmpp

Hi I am new to IPhone development and i don't know anything in Objective c. I am developing an application using swift. I added XMPP framework in to my project and the XMPP connection was successful. I am using the following code to set up my connection

```
func setupStream () {

        xmppStream = XMPPStream()
        xmppStream!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        xmppReconnect = XMPPReconnect();
        xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage();
        xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage);



        xmppvCardStorage = XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
        xmppvCardTempModule = XMPPvCardTempModule(withvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage);

        xmppvCardAvatarModule = XMPPvCardAvatarModule(withvCardTempModule:xmppvCardTempModule);

        xmppCapabilitiesStorage = XMPPCapabilitiesCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
        xmppCapabilities = XMPPCapabilities(capabilitiesStorage: xmppCapabilitiesStorage);

        // SET UP ALL XMPP MODULES
        xmppRoster!.autoFetchRoster = true;
        xmppRoster!.autoAcceptKnownPresenceSubscriptionRequests = true;

        xmppCapabilities!.autoFetchHashedCapabilities = true;
        xmppCapabilities!.autoFetchNonHashedCapabilities = true;

        xmppMessageArchivingStorage = XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance();
        xmppMessageArchivingModule = XMPPMessageArchiving(messageArchivingStorage: xmppMessageArchivingStorage);
        xmppMessageArchivingModule!.clientSideMessageArchivingOnly = true;


        // Activate xmpp modules
        xmppReconnect!.activate(xmppStream);
        xmppRoster!.activate(xmppStream);
        xmppvCardTempModule!.activate(xmppStream);
        xmppvCardAvatarModule!.activate(xmppStream);
        xmppCapabilities!.activate(xmppStream);
        xmppMessageArchivingModule!.activate(xmppStream);


        xmppRoster!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue());
        xmppMessageArchivingModule!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue());


          }
```

And the following methods are working fine

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream?, didReceiveMessage: XMPPMessage?) {
}


func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream?, didReceivePresence: XMPPPresence?) {
}
```

Now I want to get the roster list from XMPP. I found a delegate method in the roster class

```
(void)xmppRosterDidEndPopulating:(XMPPRoster *)sender;
```

But how to use this in the Swift class. Please help me....

Comment: Perhaps you  should set a delegate to XMPPRoster?

Comment: Finally i got the answer   
func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(sender: XMPPRoster?){
        var jidList = xmppRosterStorage?.jidsForXMPPStream(xmppStream)
        println("List=\(jidList)")
        
    }

Answer (score 2):

finally i got the asnwer by setting the delegate like this

```
func xmppRosterDidEndPopulating(sender: XMPPRoster?){
        var jidList = xmppRosterStorage?.jidsForXMPPStream(xmppStream)
        println("List=\(jidList)")

    }
```

Comment: hi your code helped me lot and saved my hours. I'm working on swift and I have crash in "NSParameterAssert(storage != nil);" in XMPP classes which are in objective c. Any idea what you have do for that?

Comment: This is regarding which functionality in XMPP?